# Write variables to existing CSV across columns

Tags: powershell, export-csv

This is a two part question about the limits of `Out-File` and turning string values into objects to use `Export-CSV`.

I am working on a script to pull various information and add it to an existing csv doc. I am currently using `Out-File` but I do no think it has the desired functionality.

```
$date, $computerName, $env:UserName, 'error' | Out-File $report -Append
```

The above adds all the data in a single column, for instance:

```
date
computername
username
error
```

I would like it to read:

```
date computername username error
```

I have tried using `Export-CSV`, but since my variables are strings it just writes the string length instead of the variable. I am happy to use `Export-CSV` with `-Append` so long as it reports the items correctly.

Bonus points if we can get the table to have headers like:

```
date computername username error
8/15/2018 A1 Bob PowerIssue
8/15/2018 A2 Tom InternetIssue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$date, $computerName, $env:UserName, 'error'` is a collection which is getting converted to an array of strings. So then `Out-File` takes each element of that array and spits it out one element per line.

You could generate a single string. For example,

```
"$date, $computerName, $env:UserName, error" | Out-File $report -Append
```

But the better way would be to make an object then export that to csv. Here's an example using `[pscustomobject]` which requires PS3+

```
$ExampleObjects = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Date         = Get-Date
        ComputerName = 'A1'
        UserName     = 'Bob'
        Error        = 'PowerIssue'
    },
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Date         = Get-Date
        ComputerName = 'A2'
        UserName     = 'Tom'
        Error        = 'InternetIssue'
    }
)

$ExampleObjects | Export-CSV $report -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This works well. To all other readers, you can input variables in place of the specific items @BenH mentioned above ('A1', 'Bob' etc.). Thanks for the help, this is what I needed.